# Hugo Error: no existing content directory configured for this project

Tags: go, hugo

Me aparece ese error cuando intento crear nuevo contenido en mi servidor Hugo en Ubuntu.
En el directorio raíz tengo un archivo config.toml con este contenido:

```
baseURL = 'https://mytraveltreasury/'
languageCode = 'en-us'
title = 'My Travel Treasury'
theme = 'ananke'


[params]
  commentoEnable = true
  
[languages]
  [languages.en]
    title = "My Travel Treasury"
    weight = 1
    contentDir = "content/en"
    # languageDirection = 'rtl' for Right-To-Left languages
  [languages.it]
    title = "My Travel Treasury IT"
    weight = 2
    contentDir = "content/it"
  [languages.es]
    title = "My Travel Treasury ES"
    weight = 3
    contentDir = "content/es"    
[[params.ananke_socials]]
name = "twitter"
url = "https://twitter.com/GoHugoIO"
```

y he creado un archivo adicional también en el raíz, llamado config.toml que contiene una única línea para decirle dónde debería poner el contenido:

```
contentDir = "content"
```

He comprobado que en mi directorio raíz, tengo una carpeta que se llama content, y he creado de manera manual un archivo nuevo llamado index.md.

He arrancado el servidor hugo y lo he apagado y posteriormente, estoy tratando de crear mi primer post para mi blog con el comando, hugo new content content/first.md, pero me sale el error: Error: no existing content directory configured for this project

Qué puede estar mal para que siga dando ese error?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado el error.

Tenía definidos tres ubicaciones para el contentDir para los tres idiomas en el fichero hugo.toml además del nuevo que había configurado en el archivo config.toml.

Este archivo ya no se utiliza y no es necesario, por lo que he eliminado el archivo config.toml y editado el hugo.toml dejando únicamente un contentDir en la ubicación content.

De este modo, he reiniciado el servidor y ya puedo crear mis archivos de contenido.

Comment: No está demás que menciones con qué versión de hugo estás trabajando. _hugo.toml_ es el nuevo _config.toml_ desde la [versión 0.110.0](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/tag/v0.110.0).